# DropDown Navigation for Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am trying to create a dropdown menu on my navigation in WordPress, using Custom Post Type categories as the dropdown. For Example, In Products, I have 6 different categories:

```
Category A
Category B
Category C
Category D
Category E
Category F
```

If I go to Appearance > Menus, I have the option to tick my categories and add them to menu. When I do this, I get the following:

[image: Invalid]

Is there an easy solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use get_categories and roll your own menu without using menu_nav() function.

```
<?php
$args=array(
'post_type'                => 'category',
'child_of'                 => 0,
'parent'                   => '',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 1,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'exclude'                  => '',
'include'                  => '',
'number'                   => '',
'pad_counts'               => false
);

$categories=get_categories($args);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
if ( $category->parent > 0 ) {
    continue;
}
```